# Html.ValidationMessage won't show error in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, error-handling

I am trying to add error on my own using `ModelState.AddModelError`, and when I try to display it on view, validation span is in html, but there is no message.

**Controller**

```
if (!paymentTypeId.HasValue || !shipmentTypeId.HasValue)
{
 var model = new CheckoutViewModel()
 {
     ShipmentTypes = m_ShipmentTypeService.GetAllShipmentTypes(true),
     PaymentTypes = m_PaymentTypeService.GetAllPaymentTypes(true),
  };
  SetBaseProperties(model, null);
  ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorCheckout", "L_CHOOSE_TYPE_ERROR");
  return View(model);
}
```

**View**

`@Html.ValidationMessage("ErrorCheckout", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

On other pages I did same and it worket, I don't know what is problem here

Comment: Before you return, does `model` have the validation set? I don't know this for sure, but I would expect `AddModelError` to operate on the model received as the argument, not the one you newed up manually.

Comment: @Crowcoder error is added, I will try to send request by submit, now I am doing by ajax, I don't have any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in sending request to Action via ajax. When I changed to Html.Form and placed submit, it started working, strange behavior, but here you go.